# prevent characters in text box in php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to prevent user to input few characters like `;` and `\` and `/`.  I now it need jquery to do, but i cant find one

The jquery will used in name. zip code input to prevent such characters etc.

please show me  an example as i new to jquery and php

Comment: Hi,

I need to create a serial number automatically when user register bike
every bike will have unique serial number.

format: JS-XXXXXX-A
where JS is fixed 
where x is random number and alphabet 
where A is alphabet(need a simple algorithm to find the alphabet  )

Comment: See my answer and write your opinion. If you have other question you need to asking another in new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.which` to getting code of pressed key and use `return false` to preventing enter of character.

```js
$("input").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 186 || e.which === 191 || e.which === 220){
        console.log("This character can't entered");
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job. I hope you can read this simple code:

```
// select css classes 'input' and assign onKeyDown event to them
$(".input").keydown(function(event) {
    // check what key is pressed. dot is not allowed in  this case
    if ( event.keyCode === 190) {
        // prevent event to happen
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[On the bottom of this page](http://www.mediaevent.de/javascript/Extras-Javascript-Keycodes.html) there is a small table for some codes and also an input field which shows you key code for particular key. Just as a helper, to let you find codes for wished key faster.